# Convert a Mono's list to Flux

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactor

I have the following model :

```
class Person {
    List<Address> addresses;
}
```

I used the `ReactiveMongoRepository` to retrieve a Mono.

```
public interface PersonRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Person, String>{
}
```

But I can't find a way to retrieve a Flux of addresses (from a list of person's addresses).
Here is the signature of what I want to achieve :

```
Flux<Addresses> getAddressesByPersonId(String personId)
```

I tried the following :

```
public Flux<Addresses> getAddressesByPersonId(String personId){
    Mono<Person> person = personRepository.findById(personId);
    return person.map(e -> e.getAdresses()).flux()
}
```

But I got the error :

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Flux<List<Person>> to Flux<Person>
```

**Question:** How can I retrieve a flux of addresses stored as a List for a given `Person` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use flatMapMany.  It's flatMap with the extra kink of making the transition to the Flux world from Mono.

```
public Flux<Addresses> getAddressesByPersonId(String personId){
    Mono<Person> person = personRepository.findById(personId);
    return person.flatMapMany(e -> e.getAddresses()).flux()
}
```

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html

> The rx operators will offer aliases for input Mono type to preserve the "at most one" property of the resulting Mono. For instance flatMap returns a Mono, while there is a flatMapMany alias with possibly more than 1 emission.